# Sveltekit Apollo Client build errors

Tags: svelte, apollo-client, sveltekit

Having issues to build my sveltekit app after installing/using ApolloClient.

`npm run dev` *functions fine* but shows an error in terminal:

```
(node:38924) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Believe my imports are fine, they don't throw errors:

```
import { ApolloClient } from "@apollo/client/core/ApolloClient.js";
import { InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/cache/inmemory/inMemoryCache.js";
import { setClient } from 'svelte-apollo';
```

*The issues occur when* I try build in Vercel (or locally) I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@apollo/client/core' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /vercel/path0/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/index.svelte.js
Did you mean to import @apollo/client/core/core.cjs?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:433:17)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1009:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1218:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:580:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:294:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36)
[vite-plugin-svelte-kit] 500 /
error during build:
Error: 500 /
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/vite.js:1126:11
    at save (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/vite.js:1399:4)
    at visit (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/vite.js:1290:3)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```